# Salesforce Mobile SDK issue with Xcode 9

Tags: salesforcemobilesdk-ios, mobilesdk

I have used salesforce mobile sdk 4.3 in Xcode 8.3. It is working fine but after updating to Xcode 9 it is crashing while tapping on gear icon in Login screen.

Crash error:
unable to dequeue a cell with identifier SFDCLoginHostListCellIdentifier - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard.

Answer (score 2):

Please upgrade to Mobile SDK 6.0 to use Xcode 9 and 7.0 to use Xcode 10.  When Apple updates Xcode it typically requires code change (often breaking changes) to the SDK.  More documentation can be found below.

[What's New in 6.0](https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-iOS/tree/v6.0.0#whats-new-in-60)

[What's New in 7.0](https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-iOS/tree/v7.0.0#whats-new-in-70)

[Latest documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mobile_sdk.meta/mobile_sdk/gs_whatsnew.htm)

Comment: Hi Brandon, welcome to SFSE! Do you have any documentation references to help flesh out the answer?

Comment: @DavidReed Sure, I just update the answer.  Thanks!